# Django (1.6) Login status success or not?

Tags: django, authentication, authorization

Does Djangos login view return any "status" variable when a login is successful? That I can use in my Jquery function. I want to load the response (profile) in another div if it's successful and the current div if the form got errors. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include this in your `<head>`:

```
<script>var logged_in={{ request.user.is_authenticated|lower }};</script>
```

If you want information on the user that you can use in multiple usecases you can add this to urls.py:

```
urlpatterns += patterns('', url(r'^loggedinuser/$'),
            lambda r:'{"is_logged_in":"%s"}'%r.user.is_authenticated)
```

You can of course expand upon this, add other features you want revealed.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure how to use this though. On my index base page I load a type of modal-box with a child startpage inside. This is where I have a login-form in a certain div. I post this with jquery and on login-success I want the profile to load in the -parentbox not in the form-div. But maybe i need to rethink it all.

Comment: At least this provides you with what you asked for: inlining information about logged-in status for use in javascript.  I'm happy to address some other use case if you edit the question.

Comment: Yeah sure :) but i was thinking more of some kind of status in the returned context from the view. Without rewriting my own login-view. But maybe I'll find a way to use this. Thanks anyway

Comment: You can very easily get a json object for the logged in user with one line in urls.py, i'll add it to the answer.